# pod trunk push error

Tags: cocoapods

Here is my podspec:

```ruby
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name         = "MXMarkdownKeyboard"
  s.version      = "0.0.3"
  s.summary      = "MarkdwonKeyboard for iOS"
  s.homepage     = "https://github.com/mexiQQ/MXMarkdownKeyboard"
  s.license      = { :type => "MIT", :file => "LICENSE.md" }
  s.author       = { "mexiqq" => "ljw040426@gmail.com" }
  s.platform     = :ios
  s.source       = { :git => "https://github.com/mexiQQ/MXMarkdownKeyboard.git",:tag => '0.0.3'}
  s.source_files  = "MXMarkdownKeyboard", "MXMarkdownKeyboard/*.{h,m}"
end
```

The repo is here: https://github.com/mexiQQ/MXMarkdownKeyboard

When I execute `pod spec lint` it returns:

```ruby
MXMarkdownKeyboard.podspec passed validation.
```

But, when I execute `pod trunk push` I get this error:

```ruby
[!] The Pod Specification did not pass validation.
```

How can I fix this and push my spec to trunk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's expecting a file called LICENSE in the root of your repo, but it can't find one.

Comment: It's not in the 0.0.2 tag: https://github.com/mexiQQ/MXMarkdownKeyboard/tree/0.0.2

Comment: now I fix the question:  `[!] Unable to read the license file /private/tmp/CocoaPods/Lint/Pods/MXMarkdownKeyboard/LICENSE for the spec `MXMarkdownKeyboard (0.0.2)` ,but `[!] The Pod Specification did not pass validation.` is still bad

Comment: What error are you getting now that you have updated to `0.0.3`?

Comment: It's OK,because I lack 's.requires_arc = true'